# How to hide homegroup, this pc and Network drop-down lists from left sidebar of Windows Explorer?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, desktop-customization, homegroup

I try to find some info about hiding elements (homegroup, this pc and Network drop-down lists) from left sidebar of windows explorer, but I can't find anything. Maybe, there are any reg tweaks?

[image]

So, these are the results of my research:

**To hide HomeGroup** I disabled two windows services: `HomeGroupListener` and `HomeGroupProvider`.

**To hide 'This PC'** i used this guide: https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8959-computer-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-8-explorer.html

**To hide Network** use [this](https://superuser.com/a/1125659/642513) answer.

Comment: Good luck... you can always turn off network discovery to block homegroups in firewall using Homegroup options

Comment: Thanks. I also found a way to disable This PC from left pane (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8959-computer-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-8-explorer.html) but not from adress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is avail on web here.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8636-network-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-8-explorer.html

For Win8.1

- To Remove "Network" from the Navigation Pane

  - [win] + [r] (run)  regedit  [enter] ... accept if UAC prompted
  - drill down to
  - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder1
  - If you have not already, then in the left pane of regedit, take ownership of and set permissions to "Allow" the Administrators group "Full control" of the ShellFolder registry key
  - Change value of **attributes** in one digit  to b0**9**40064   then OK (enter)
  - to restore icon for Networks, change **9** back to **0**
- [Alt+F4] or [X] close, logout/login or restart explorer in task manager or Reboot

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.